# Is there an way of storing this to memory instead of a text file?

Tags: c#

I have this piece of code which repeats about 250,000 on a loop searching through the records. There are 28 different Regex (this being one of them). Is there an easier way other than writing to a file, reading it into a string and using each towards the end of my code?

```
if (CSV_Radio_Button.Checked)
   {
       string pattern = @"(?<=\*\*Course : )(.*?)(?=\*\*Going)";
       Regex myRegex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
       Match m = myRegex.Match(text); 
       while (m.Success)
       {
           string CourseToString = m.ToString();
           System.IO.File.WriteAllText(CourseFile, UppercaseWords(CourseToString));
           m = m.NextMatch();            
       }
    }
    string Course = File.ReadLines(CourseFile).ElementAtOrDefault(0);
```

Comment: ... using a list I guess?

Comment: Given that storing data in variables is like first hour of learning C# - what except "do it" do you expect as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but this is how I've done something similar.  A list would work but you'd be iterating over the list when you are done to build the string. You could also use one of the various Streams.

```
 StringBuilder CourseBuilder = new StringBuilder();

while (m.Success)
   {
       CourseBuilder.AppendLine(m.ToString());
       m = m.NextMatch();            
   }
}
string Course = CourseBuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intentionally overwriting file here:

```
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(CourseFile, UppercaseWords(CourseToString));
```

you can replace that line with string defined before your block like this:

```
string CSV_regex_result;
if (CSV_Radio_Button.Checked)
{
    ...
    while(m.Success) {
        CSV_regex_result = UppercaseWords(m.ToString());
        m = m.NextMatch(); 
    }
}
```

Now you can access last matched regex in `CSV_regex_result`.

If there is mistake in code and you want all regex it depends, if you want it separated or not. 
If you want single string David Green answer is way to go. *But be careful about string size limit.*

If you want separated results:
Replace in my example `string CSV_regex_result;` with `List<string> CSV_regex_result = new List<string>();` and in loop replace `CSV_regex_result = UppercaseWords(m.ToString());` with `CSV_regex_result.Add(UppercaseWords(m.ToString()));`.

If you want results accessible separated by regex name. You can:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> result = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
...
List<string> Course_result = new List<string>();    
...
//in loop
Course_result.Add(UppercaseWords(m.ToString()));
...
//after loop
if (!result.ContainsKey("Course")) result.Add("Course",Course_result);
else result["Course"]=Course_result;
```

Of course if you want merged results of regex you can create `Dictionary<string,string>` and add results generated with StringBuilder.

*In case will run out of memory (depends on your memory size and data amount) it can be good to stick with your current approach (save parts to files).*